# Knitting a Markdown pdf with only a few modifications

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown script that takes more than two hours to run.

Sometimes I just want to make a small modification and knit it again to a pdf, but it seems like a waste of time to run the whole script for hours just for that little change.

Is there any way I can "save" what I've already knitted, so that when I knit again with a small change, it can knit only the part where it's changed?

Comment: you can specify ```{r,cache=T}``` to save particular chunk

Comment: You might also look into the`targets` package. "The targets package is a Make-like pipeline tool for Statistics and data science in R. With targets, you can maintain a reproducible workflow without repeating yourself. targets learns how your pipeline fits together, skips costly runtime for tasks that are already up to date, runs only the necessary computation, supports implicit parallel computing, abstracts files as R objects, and shows tangible evidence that the results match the underlying code and data." https://books.ropensci.org/targets/